# What is the difference between or-tools and python-mip, e.g. performance, correctness?

Tags: or-tools

or-tools claims the competition is consistently gold (https://developers.google.com/optimization) and python-mip claims to be the fastest open source linear programming solver (http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/lpsimp. html), so which one is faster?

Crossposted from https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3449

Comment: The best way to measure performance would be to try it in the specific problem and see the results. Or start with one framework and switch to the other if the first does not satisfy you. The results might vary depending on the input. Both tools should be good to go.

Comment: or-tools has wrappers (using, among others, the same solver als python-mip: CoinOR Cbc) and own solvers (like CP-SAT). Using Cbc in both is basically the same, while Cbc vs. CP-SAT depends on your problem specifics. There are also problems which CP-SAT cannot solve (it knows no continuous variables). "Which one is faster" for specific problems is hard to predict and you should measure. Over a broad set of instances, CoinOR Cbc might not be the gold-standard for MILP anymore (compared to Highs; see your link, but MILP, not LP),but this alternative solver is probably not available in both (yet).

Comment: The gold medals were won on the minizinc challenge. It benchmarks multiple solvers and technologies (MIP, cp, sat, smt...) on a broad set of problems. Cp-sat has consistently scored first in the last years.